# I need some really good blogs to follow ASP.NET MVC, Fluent NHibernate, and Spark View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, spark-view-engine

I need some really good blogs to follow ASP.NET MVC, Fluent NHibernate, and Spark View Engine.
I would like to follow some good bloggers in these areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of http://dotnetshoutout.com/ as it's a site users submit their blogs, articles and code snippets on. You should be able to check the following tags for technologies you're interested in.

- [ASP.NET MVC](http://dotnetshoutout.com/Tags/ASPNET-MVC)
- [NHibernate](http://dotnetshoutout.com/Tags/NHibernate)
- [Spark](http://dotnetshoutout.com/Tags/Spark)

Answer (score 2):

You can't go wrong with [Scott Guthrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Guthrie). He runs the development teams for ASP.NET, Silverlight, IIS among others.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/

Answer (score 1):

I believe James Gregory (http://blog.jagregory.com/) is the team leader for Fluent NHibernate.

While not directly tied to the Fluent NHibernate project, Fabio Maulo (http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/) and Ayende (http://ayende.com/blog/) are critical to NHibernate in general.

I also suggest following the NHibernate group. (http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate)

Answer (score 0):

[shameless plug] You might want to take look at my [MvcExtensions](http://github.com/tojans/mvcextensions) library; it is a combination of Fluent NHibernate, Spark and some other popular open source stuff.[/shameless plug]